# Gremlin query like SQL IN operator?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

Im stuck with gremlin. I have emails like array and I need to make query to find all user with those emails.

In SQL I have

```
SELECT email(s)
FROM user
WHERE email IN (xxx, yyy...)
```

How can I do this in Gremlin query language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wanna do here is:

```
g.V().has('anyProperty', within('possibleValue1', 'possibleValue2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable for you to do a linear scan of all vertices, then you could do something like:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> s = ['marko','josh'] as Set
==>marko
==>josh
gremlin> g.V.filter{s.contains(it.name)}.name
==>marko
==>josh
```

Comment: This question also appeared on the neo4j mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/pgAHqbjumjc) where marko offered this approach which uses indices, thus avoiding the linear scan: `["s@s.com","e@e.com"].collect{g.V('email',it).name.next()}`

Answer (score 0):

g.V('table_name','User').has('email',IN,[xxx,yyy....]).transform({['email':it.getProperty('email')]})
//assuming u have a table name attribute

Comment: Welcome to the community and thank you for your answer. However, please ensure you format you code properly in the future. Providing a brief explanation on your code would also be nice.