# Gremlin equivalent of SQL 'in' clause

Tags: sql, groovy, gremlin

I'm trying to write a gremlin query to find all of the nodes that have a value that is in the set of results of another query, similar to SQL's 'in' clause.

For example:

```
select * from myTable
where someVal in (select someVal from otherTable)
```

This question may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273667/gremlin-query-like-sql-in-operator) question, but the answer given there is not applicable to me as I cannot do a linear scan of my graph as the values of my IN clause are the dynamic result of a query and not a static list.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use [retain](http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/retain).  You basically store off results of the first query and use those as input to the `retain` step so that items passing through the pipeline that match are kept.  A simple example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> firstResults = g.v(1).out.toList()
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V.retain(firstResults)
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

The `retain` step is often used in conjunction with `aggregate`:

```
gremlin> x=[]
gremlin> g.v(1).out.aggregate(x).out.retain(x)
==>v[3]
```

or you can use a named step:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).out.as('x').out.retain(x)
==>v[3]
```

For more SQL conversions to Gremlin you can check out: [SQLToGremlin.com](http://sql2gremlin.com/).